# How to get filesize and LastupdateTime from attachment in Exchange Server 2007 email account?

Tags: exchange-server

```
                    if (email.HasAttachments)
                    {
                        AttachmentList AttachmentFiles = new AttachmentList();  //class for attachment list
                        foreach (Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
                        {
                            if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                            {
                                FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
                                attachmentEntity.MailID = MailID;
                                attachmentEntity.Filename = fileAttachment.FileName;
                                attachmentEntity.FileSize = fileAttachment.Size;
                                attachmentEntity.File = fileAttachment.Content;
                                attachmentEntity.CreatedDate = fileAttachment.LastModifiedTime;
                                AttachmentFiles.Add(attachmentEntity);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I got following error.
The property Last Modified Time  and Size are valid only for Exchange Exchange 2010 or later versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get these properties in EWS in Exchange 2007 the only way to get the size of an attachment would be to download the attachment. In 2007 you should still be able to use WebDAV https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms877930(v=exchg.65).aspx which you can get this information from without needing to do the download otherwise look at using MAPI via Outlook/Redemption.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Is there any way to get file size and date other than you have suggested above for Exchange 2007?

Comment: Not with EWS on 2007 as I said use another API either MAPI or WebDAV